# What can I do when my verilog code worked in Simulation and online debugging with ILA but not barely on FPGA?

Tags: verilog, fpga, uart

I am using Verilog to write a quite simple UART send demo. This demo will send out a number after certain seconds. Say the first time it will be 0x00 and the second time it will be 0x01. Every time it will add up one on the previous number.

I used an ila ip core to debug my code and I fixed problems and everything went fine when I had ila in my code. This is what I got in the serial port tool on my PC:

[image]

However, after I delete ila in the code. The demo only sent out the number 0x00 and stopped. And I noticed **tx** is low after sending out 0x00.

[image]

I don't know how to continue debugging this code now.

Here is my code:

```
module uart_send(
    input clk,
    input send_flag,
    input reset,
    input [7:0]data,
    input [2:0]baud_set,
    output reg tx_done,
    output reg tx
    );
    
    parameter CLK_FREQ = 50000000;
    
    reg [15:0] baud_cnt;
    reg [15:0] baud;
    reg [3:0] bit_cnt;
/*
ila_0 your_instance_name (
    .clk(clk), // input wire clk


    .probe0(bit_cnt), // input wire [3:0]  probe0  
    .probe1(baud_cnt), // input wire [15:0]  probe1 
    .probe2(tx_done), // input wire [0:0]  probe2 
    .probe3(tx), // input wire [0:0]  probe3 
    .probe4(send_flag) // input wire [0:0]  probe4
);*/

    //choose baud rate
    always@(*)
    begin
        case(baud_set)
            0: baud = CLK_FREQ/9600;
            1: baud = CLK_FREQ/115200;
            
            default: baud = CLK_FREQ/115200;
        endcase        
    end
    
    always@(posedge clk, negedge reset) begin   
    if(!reset) begin
        baud_cnt <= 16'h0000;
        bit_cnt <= 4'b0000;
    end
    else begin
        if(baud_cnt == baud-1) begin
            baud_cnt <= 16'h0000;
            bit_cnt <= bit_cnt + 1;
        end
        else
            baud_cnt <= baud_cnt + 1;
    end
    
    if(!reset) begin
        bit_cnt <= 4'b0000;
    end
    else begin
        if(bit_cnt == 11)
            bit_cnt <= 4'b0000;
    end
    
    if(send_flag) begin
        if(reset) begin
            case(bit_cnt)
                0: begin tx <= 0; tx_done <= 0; end
                1: tx <= data[0];
                2: tx <= data[1];
                3: tx <= data[2];
                4: tx <= data[3];
                5: tx <= data[4];
                6: tx <= data[5];
                7: tx <= data[6];
                8: tx <= data[7];
                9: tx <= 1;
                10: begin tx <= 1; tx_done <= 1; end
                
                default: tx <= 1;
            endcase     
        end      
        else begin
            tx <= 1;
            tx_done <= 0;
        end
    end
    else begin
        tx <= 1;
        tx_done <= 0;
        bit_cnt <= 4'b0000;
        baud_cnt <= 16'h0000;
    end
    end

endmodule

module uart_tx_test(
    input clk,
    input reset,
    output data_out,
    output reg led
    );
    
    parameter CLK_FREQ = 50000000;
    
    reg send_flag;
    //reg baud_set;
    reg [7:0] data;
    wire tx_done;
    
    reg [19:0] div_cnt;
    reg [23:0] led_cnt;
    //reg [19:0] div_limit;
    
    
    uart_send u1(
        .clk(clk),
        .send_flag(send_flag),
        .reset(reset),
        .baud_set(3'b001),
        .data(data),
        .tx(data_out),
        .tx_done(tx_done)
    );
    
    
    
    always@(posedge clk, negedge reset) begin
        if(!reset) begin
            div_cnt <= 20'h00000;
            led_cnt <= 24'h00000;
            send_flag <= 0;
            data <= 0;
            led <= 0;
        end
        else begin
            if(div_cnt == 499999) begin
                div_cnt <= 20'h00000;
                data <= data + 1;
                send_flag <= 1;
            end
            else begin
                div_cnt <= div_cnt + 1;
                //send_flag <= 0;
            end    
            
            if(tx_done) begin
                send_flag <= 0;
            end 
            
            if(led_cnt == 9999999) begin
                led_cnt <= 24'h00000;
                led <= ~led;
            end  
            else begin
                led_cnt <= led_cnt + 1;
            end    
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score -2):

something wrong with my send_flag signal in the uart_send block, I changed my code and it is ok now.

```
    module uart_send(
    input clk,
    input send_flag,
    input reset,
    input [7:0]data,
    input [2:0]baud_set,
    output reg tx_done,
    output reg tx
    );
    
    parameter CLK_FREQ = 50000000;
    
    reg [15:0] baud_cnt;
    reg [15:0] baud;
    reg [3:0] bit_cnt;

    //choose baud rate
    always@(*)
    begin
        case(baud_set)
            0: baud = CLK_FREQ/9600;
            1: baud = CLK_FREQ/115200;
            
            default: baud = CLK_FREQ/115200;
        endcase        
    end
    
    always@(posedge clk, negedge reset) begin   
        if(!reset) begin
            baud_cnt <= 16'h0000;
            bit_cnt <= 4'b0000;
        end
        else begin
            if(baud_cnt == baud-1) begin
                baud_cnt <= 16'h0000;
                bit_cnt <= bit_cnt + 1;
            end
            else
                baud_cnt <= baud_cnt + 1;
        end
    
        if(!reset) begin
            bit_cnt <= 4'b0000;
        end
        else begin
            if(bit_cnt == 11)
                bit_cnt <= 4'b0000;
        end
    
        if(!reset) begin
            tx <= 1;
            tx_done <= 0;
        end
        else begin
            if(send_flag) begin
                case(bit_cnt)
                    0: begin tx <= 0; tx_done <= 0; end
                    1: tx <= data[0];
                    2: tx <= data[1];
                    3: tx <= data[2];
                    4: tx <= data[3];
                    5: tx <= data[4];
                    6: tx <= data[5];
                    7: tx <= data[6];
                    8: tx <= data[7];
                    9: tx <= 1;
                    10: begin tx <= 1; tx_done <= 1; end
                    
                    default: tx <= 1;
                endcase     
            end
            else begin
                tx <= 1;
                tx_done <= 0;
                bit_cnt <= 4'b0000;
                baud_cnt <= 16'h0000;
            end
        end
    end
endmodule
```